# Animate elements into view on scroll

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-animate

I am trying to achieve the effect shown here: http://campaignlabs.com/

When the page scrolls to a section, animate that sections elements in either with a fade or slide. Is there a jQuery library that will allow me to do this easily or will I have to write a custom script? It appears my example provided above wrote something custom for this.

Answer (score 0):

I  think you should use [jquery.visible.js](https://github.com/customd/jquery-visible) plugin.